# AWS Glue Crawler glob Exclude Pattern functionality

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

We need to ignore a few paths while crawling through a specific path. Below are the details:

```
Include Path: s3://dev-bronze/api/sp/reports/xyz/
Exclude Path: brand=abc/client=xxx/**
```

Full path : "s3://dev-bronze/api/sp/reports/xyz/brand=abc/client=xxx/"

We want to ignore a few client's data. So I am using the above glob but it doesn't seem to work. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share an example of the full object key of an object in the `client=xxx` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clarifying the difference between exclude patterns `brand=abc/client=xxx/**` and `brand=abc/client=xxx**` (note the missing `/`).

Exclude pattern `brand=abc/client=xxx/**` matches:

```
s3://dev-bronze/api/sp/reports/xyz/brand=abc/client=xxx/<subfolder1>/file1.txt
s3://dev-bronze/api/sp/reports/xyz/brand=abc/client=xxx/<subfolder2>/file2.txt
```

This pattern will match objects in all subfolders of `brand=abc/client=xxx/`.

Exclude pattern `brand=abc/client=xxx**` matches:

```
s3://dev-bronze/api/sp/reports/xyz/brand=abc/client=xxx/file1.txt
s3://dev-bronze/api/sp/reports/xyz/brand=abc/client=xxx/file2.txt
```

This pattern will match all objects in `brand=abc/client=xxx/`.

If you want to exclude files in `brand=abc/client=xxx/`, then use the exclude pattern `brand=abc/client=xxx**`.

Reference: [Crawler Properties > Include and Exclude Patterns (AWS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/define-crawler.html#crawler-data-stores-exclude)